# Big noob in statistics -- I have Yes/No data; how can I analyze this?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

My study consists of data from both men and women; I wanted to correlate their answers to yes/no questions to their enjoyability in a course on a scale from one to ten.

What would be the best statistical data test to use to correlate the yes no data to 1-10 scale data while keeping it divided between men and women? Can this be done? If so, could you explain it in layman's terms?

Answer (score 3):

Don't test, just show the charts and descriptive stats.

The main reason for my suggestion is that from the text of your question it appears that your sample is too small, and the yes/no variables may not be *valid*, because you may not have tested this. Here, I'm using the term in a narrow context of [reliability and validity](https://www.uni.edu/chfasoa/reliabilityandvalidity.htm) in qualitative analysis.

Unlike with physical measures, when you measure the length of an object with a measuring tape, in qualitative analysis things are much muddier: there's no tape to measure satisfaction. In your case enjoyability - how do you know that your variables actually measure it properly?

What is enjoyability? Some people enjoy pain, they may answer 'yes' when you whip their arses, while most folks will hate it and answer 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

you could try logistic regression with the dependent variable as your yes/no outcome, the 1-10 scale variable as a continuous predictor, and sex as a dichotomous predictor. That is probably a good start and should give you relatively interpretable results.

Answer (score 0):

Next to @Aksakal and @bdeonovic's answers, you could also do a linear regression with the 1-10 scale as dependent (aka outcome) and use sex and the yes/no questions as independent variables (aka predictors).

Using logistic or linear regression you could also add interaction terms to see whether one of the predictors influence the effect of another.

So if you were using linear regression with enjoyability as outcome: you can see multiple effects:

1. the effect of sex (being male or being female) on enjoyability
2. the effect of answering Yes (or no) to a specific question on enjoyability
3. the effect of sex on the effect on enjoyability of answering Yes to a specific question (interaction effect)

However **most important is to decide upon a research goal/question** and, as @Aksakal writes, then get a feel of your data by looking at the charts and descriptive stats. Any modeling comes after.

IMHO though, do note that "checking whether variables are correlated" in itself, is hardly a research question. 
I say this, because the reason why this correlation is important to you, *and* considering the data that is available to you, can give rise to a broad range of options, some probably less suitable than others.